# How to train new labels in NLTK for name entity recognition

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, nltk-trainer

i am new to python I need to extract a job titles from text and I need to know how to train data for name entity recognition and where to train the data

Comment: I think you should first search for tutorials and start experimenting yourself. We will help you with problems in your code, but we will not write the code _for you_.

Comment: BTW, here's a rule-based NER, very silly but fun =) https://gist.github.com/alvations/73bce71acf229265bc08

Answer (score 0):

To train a named-entity recognizer or other chunker with custom categories (including job titles), you need a corpus that is annotated with the categories you are interested in. Then you can read the nltk book, especially chapter 7.2 on [chunking](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#chunking), which shows you how to train a chunker with the nltk.

Comment: Good to hear that. So what is your question now exactly?

Comment: the problem which i had is we had a large amount resumes i need to extract job titles for eg: school teacher,software developer...i did this ur help tq

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what "i did this ur help tq" is supposed to abbreviate. Are you saying that you followed my suggestion and were able to solve your problem? If so, please "accept" my answer by clicking on the big check mark on the left, to mark your question resolved. (If not, please try again in complete sentences.)